# HTML5 File System API error "Cannot read property 'root' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, html, undefined, getfiles

When I try to write a file I am getting this error in Google Chrome:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'root' of undefined FileSystemApi.html:29
onButtonSaveClick FileSystemApi.html:29
onclick
```

My sample code is as follows

```
var fileSys;

$(function () {
    initFileSystem(onInitFileSystemSuccess);
});

function onInitFileSystemSuccess(fs) {
    console.log('Opened file system: ' + fs.name);
    fileSys = fs;
}

function onButtonSaveClick() {
    alert('1');
    var fileName = $("#fileName").val();
    alert(fileName);
    var fileContent = $("#fileContent").val();
    alert(fileContent);
    alert(fileSys.root);
    fileSys.root.getFile(fileName, {
            create: true,
            exclusive: true
        },
        function (fileEntry) {
            alert('2');
            console.log('File opened: ' + fileEntry.fullPath);
            fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {
                var blob = new Blob([fileContent], {
                    type: 'text/plain'
                });
                fileWriter.write(blob);
                alert('done');
            }, onFileSystemError);
        }, onFileSystemError);
}
```

Would anyone be able to point out the problem(s), and, if so, contribute a solution?

Comment: where is fileSys defined? I don't see it defined anywhere

Comment: Provide a jsFiddle replicating the issue please.

Comment: Possible reason: Your `onButtonSaveClick` is executed before `onInitFileSystemSuccess` resulting in `fileSys` still being `undefined`. But provide a fiddle please.